# Как заставить браузер кэшировать изображение

Tags: php, javascript, html

У меня на странице все изображения загружаются через скрипт, т.е. через `script.php?path=path/to.image`.

Проблема в том, что браузер не кэширует изображения по таким ссылкам и ему приходится каждый раз при заходе на страницу их загружать, т.е. тратить дополнительный трафик. Как можно заставить браузер кэшировать эти изображения?

Comment: Чем вызвана необходимость применять такое решение?

Comment: Во многих местах эти изображения имеют разный размер. Для максимальной оптимизации скрипт эти изображения скалирует под запрошенный размер.
Плюс защита. Если пользователь не авторизирован, то он не сможет получить доступ к изображению.

Comment: Не по теме: боюсь, такой скрипт будет жрать крайне много ресурсов, всё-таки изменение размера картинки операция не самая быстрая

Comment: Если у вас картинко-сервис а винты не позволяют, вам надо смотреть в сторону картинко-хостингов и храниться там. Если у вас картинок на 2-4гига - не жмитесь, закешируйте один раз и выдавайте. Проверку авторизации можно и нужно выполнять выше. А с постоянной генерацией вам 10 юзеров положат сайт :)

Comment: Допустим, проверка авторизации стоит выше. Тогда ничего не мешает прописать путь сразу к картинке, обходя эту проверку. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: товарищи, никто не мешает скрипту генерировать картинку под размер при первом обращении и сохранять, потом уже выдавать сохраненную. При этом сохраняя весь функционал проверки прав для открытия и т.п. Это в целом нормальная практика, которая встроена во многие CMS. Правда в этом случае не имеет смысла передавать путь к картинке. Должен передаваться какой то ID, и параметры схемы размеров.

Comment: Отлично, а как заставить браузер ее сохранять?

Comment: [дак заголовки то выдаете соответствующие?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7324564/1216425)

Comment: Вот с этого и надо было начинать. Большое спасибо. Можете написать это как ответ, чтобы я отметил?

Comment: пожалуйста, написал ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для кэширования контента выводимого скриптом необходимо явным образом выставить соответствующие HTTP-заголовки, сообщающие браузеру о том, можно ли и где кэшировать ответ, на какое максимальное время, какова дата истечения его актуальности. Время жизни указывается  секундах.:

> ```
> header('Pragma: public');
> header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');
> header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 86400));
> header('Content-Type: image/png');
> ```

([оригинал кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324564/1216425))

Заголовки типа контента (`Content-Type`) вы, наверное, и так выставляете, а если нет, то должны выставить в соответствие с типом вашего изображения (`image/gif`, `image/jpeg`, `image/png` и т.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Заголовки динамическим картинкам само собой не достаточно прописать. Так как "файл" отдает не сервер, а php скрипт.
Это значит - что и сам php скрипт должен обращаться к кешу браузера ( 304 редиректом )

```
    $header = apache_request_headers(); // считываем заголовок запроса браузера

if (isset($header['If-Modified-Since']) && (strtotime($header['If-Modified-Since']) < strtotime ( gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time())))) { // тут проверяем дату кеша картинки
    header('Last-Modified: '. $header['If-Modified-Since'] , true, 304);
    // если с последнего визита меньше суток - ссылаемся на кеш. На этом все.
} elseif (file_exists($_GET['route'])){ // запрос по типу https://mysite.ua/index.php?route=image/main-image.png
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 86400) . ' GMT', true, 200); // добавляем к текущей дате 24 часа ( 60 * 60 * 24 )
    header("Content-type: image/". pathinfo($_GET['route'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['route']); // сам файл картинки.
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```